# Not able to grant access to root user after installing MYSQL with brew in MAC OS

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I installed MySQL with brew using the command `brew install mysql` and it installed MySQL correctly, but it gave me instructions that say:

```
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation
```

So I ran the command `mysql_secure_installation`, and it asked me for a password for the user root, and when I entered the password, it gave me this error:

```
The user provided does not have enough permissions to continue.
mysql_secure_installation is exiting.
```

I tried running `mysql -u root -p` and entering in the sql terminal, but I am not able to run any query because I don't have access to do anything. Also, not able to grant any access to the root user.

I also tried to uninstall MySQL from my laptop and install it again, but again the same problem occurs.

Does anyone have a solution for this?